# equality on the sender of an event

Tags: c#, events, equals

I have an interface for a UI widget, two of which are attributes of a presenter.

```
public IMatrixWidget NonProjectActivityMatrix {
        set {
            // validate the incoming value and set the field
            _nonProjectActivityMatrix = value;
            ....
            // configure & load non-project activities
     }

public IMatrixWidget ProjectActivityMatrix {
        set {
            // validate the incoming value and set the field
            _projectActivityMatrix = value;
            ....
            // configure & load project activities
   }
```

The widget has an event that both presenter objects subscribe to, and so there is an event handler in the presenter like so:

```
public void OnActivityEntry(object sender, EntryChangedEventArgs e) {
    // calculate newTotal here
    ....
        if (ReferenceEquals(sender, _nonProjectActivityMatrix)) {
            _nonProjectActivityMatrix.UpdateTotalHours(feedback.ActivityTotal);
        }

        else if (ReferenceEquals(sender, _projectActivityMatrix)) {
            _projectActivityMatrix.UpdateTotalHours(feedback.ActivityTotal);
        }
        else {
            // ERROR - we should never be here
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the ReferenceEquals on the sender fails, even though it is the implemented widget that is the sender - the same implemented widget that was set to the presenter attribute!

Can anyone spot what the problem / fix is?

Cheers,
Berryl

I didn't know you could edit nicely. Cool. Here is the event raising code:

```
void OnGridViewNumericUpDownEditingControl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // omitted to save sapce

        if (EntryChanged == null) return;

        var args = new EntryChangedEventArgs(activityID, dayID, Convert.ToDouble(amount));
        EntryChanged(this, args);
    }
```

Here is the debugger dump of the presenter attribute, sans namespace info:

```
?_nonProjectActivityMatrix
{WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv}
[WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv]: {WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv}
```

Here is the debugger dump of the sender:

```
?sender
{WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv}
base {Core.GUI.Widgets.Lookup.MatrixWidgetBase<Core.GUI.Widgets.Lookup.DynamicDisplayDto>}: {WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv}
_configuration: {Domain.Presentation.Timesheet.Matrix.WeeklyMatrixConfiguration}
_wrappedWidget: {Win.Widgets.DataGridViewDynamicLookupWidget}
AllowUserToAddRows: true
ColumnCount: 11
Count: 4
EntryChanged: {Method = {Void OnActivityEntry(System.Object, Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Domain.Presentation.Timesheet.Matrix.EntryChangedEventArgs)}}
SelectedCell: {DataGridViewNumericUpDownCell { ColumnIndex=3, RowIndex=3 }}
SelectedCellValue: "0.00"
SelectedColumn: {DataGridViewNumericUpDownColumn { Name=MONDAY, Index=3 }}
SelectedItem: {'AdministrativeActivity: 130-04', , AdministrativeTime, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00}
```

- Berryl

Comment: Please add the piece of code where the Event is raised. Right now we can only guess.

Comment: What happens inside EntryChanged; do you have the code for it?

Comment: Beryl, you can Edit your original question.

Comment: Why can't you set a breakpoint and then check both variables in Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi Groo. I did do that. I'm calling that the debugger dumps in my edited question. Thx, B

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I can think of these reasons why ReferenceEquals will return false:

- `sender` is `null` - Verify that the widget sends `this` as the sender parameter when raising the event.
- The widget is not assigned to the presenter for some reason, so it is `null`
- `sender` is not what you think it is (how have you verified that it is indeed the sender you expect)
- The widget is implemented as a `struct`, not a `class`

There may be more, but this is where I would start (in that order).

**Update**: one thing that catches my eye is this:

```
_wrappedWidget: {Win.Widgets.DataGridViewDynamicLookupWidget}
```

Could it be that sender is an object that wraps your widget? If that is the case, ReferenceEquals will naturally return false when doing the comparison.

Comment: The widget is a wrapper for a DataGridView (a class). I'm checking the debugger dumps (and how I know it isn't null) to the remaining two possibilities on your list:

Here is the presenter attribute dump, complete with namespace info:
?_nonProjectActivityMatrix
{Smack.ConstructionAdmin.WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv}
    
Hi Fredrik

[Smack.ConstructionAdmin.WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv]: {Smack.ConstructionAdmin.WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv}

I don't quite get the part that looks like an index (widget[widget])

Comment: {Smack.ConstructionAdmin.WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv}
    base {Smack.Core.GUI.Widgets.Lookup.MatrixWidgetBase<Smack.Core.GUI.Widgets.Lookup.DynamicDisplayDto>}: {Smack.ConstructionAdmin.WinPresentation.Widgets.MatrixWidgetDgv}
    _configuration: {Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Domain.Presentation.Timesheet.Matrix.WeeklyMatrixConfiguration}
    _wrappedWidget: {Smack.Win.Widgets.DataGridViewDynamicLookupWidget}


I left the data grid view debugger info off.

Comment: That didn't format very well. The 2nd comment is the type info from the debugger dump of the widget.

Comment: The event raising code:
        void OnGridViewNumericUpDownEditingControl_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
  // omitted to save sapce

            if (EntryChanged == null) return;

            var args = new EntryChangedEventArgs(activityID, dayID, Convert.ToDouble(amount));
            EntryChanged(this, args);
        }

Comment: Add code samples to your original question insead; it's easier to format the code there, and it also makes the code samples easier to locate for other users that may be able to provide answers :)

Comment: No Fredrik, although the terminology in my code isn't helping here. The _wrappedWidget in the code is the DataGridView itself, and is held by the MatrixWidgetDgv. The _wrappedWidget is the original sender but my event raiser in the Matrix is passing itself as the sender. See my comments to Henk above. Thx